# How do I configure the 'Gems' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the `rubygems.org` API gem 'Gems' to search for gems and return those results in my app.

I have signed up for an api key but where do I configure it? 
I have this code from the docs but I'm not sure where to add it.

```
Gems.configure do |config|
  config.key = '701243f217cdf23b1370c7b66b65ca97'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create one file in config/initializers and create one ruby file for example rubygems_setting.rb and you put your config inside file (then reboot the server before test it)

Gems.configure do |config| config.key = '701243f217cdf23b1370c7b66b65ca97' end

I believed you need read this [rails general configuraion](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)